# How to add multiple annotations to a bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, plot-annotations

I would like to add percent values - in addition to counts - to my pandas bar plot. However, I am not able to do so. My code is shown below and thus far I can get count values to display. Can somebody please help me add relative % values next to/below the count values displayed for each bar?

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('ggplot')

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("white")

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(5)
fig.set_figwidth(10)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

counts = [29227, 102492,  53269, 504028, 802994]

y_ax = ('A','B','C','D','E')
y_tick = np.arange(len(y_ax))

ax.barh(range(len(counts)), counts, align = "center", color = "tab:blue")
ax.set_yticks(y_tick)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_ax, size = 8)

#annotate bar plot with values
for i in ax.patches:
    ax.text(i.get_width()+.09, i.get_y()+.3, str(round((i.get_width()), 1)), fontsize=8)

sns.despine()
plt.show();
```

The output of my code is shown below. How can one add % values next to each count value displayed?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`**

#### Imports and Load Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create the dataframe from values in the OP
counts = [29227, 102492,  53269, 504028, 802994]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=counts, columns=['counts'], index=['A','B','C','D','E'])

# add a percent column
df['%'] = df.counts.div(df.counts.sum()).mul(100).round(2)

# display(df)
   counts      %
A   29227   1.96
B  102492   6.87
C   53269   3.57
D  504028  33.78
E  802994  53.82
```

#### Plot with `matplotlib` from version 3.4.2

- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)

  - See [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details and examples with `.bar_label`.
  - Use `v.get_height()` instead of `v.get_width()`, if using vertical bars.
  - Some formatting can be done with the `fmt` parameter, but more sophisticated formatting should be done with the `labels` parameter.
- `pandas` uses `matplotlib` as the default plot backend.

  - Use `kind='bar'` for vertical bars.

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='barh', y='counts', figsize=(10, 5), legend=False, width=.75,
             title='This is the plot generated by all code examples in this answer')

# customize the label to include the percent
labels = [f' {v.get_width()}\n {df.iloc[i, 1]}%' for i, v in enumerate(ax.containers[0])]

# set the bar label
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=labels, label_type='edge', size=13)

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

#### Plot with `matplotlib` before version 3.4.2

```py
# plot the dataframe
ax = df.plot(kind='barh', y='counts', figsize=(10, 5), legend=False, width=.75)
for i, y in enumerate(ax.patches):

    # get the percent label
    label_per = df.iloc[i, 1]
    
    # add the value label
    ax.text(y.get_width()+.09, y.get_y()+.3, str(round((y.get_width()), 1)), fontsize=10)
    
    # add the percent label here
    ax.text(y.get_width()+.09, y.get_y()+.1, str(f'{round((label_per), 2)}%'), fontsize=10)

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

---

### Original Answer without `pandas`

- Tested with `matplotlib v3.3.4`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

counts = [29227, 102492,  53269, 504028, 802994]

# calculate percents
percents = [100*x/sum(counts) for x in counts]

y_ax = ('A','B','C','D','E')
y_tick = np.arange(len(y_ax))

ax.barh(range(len(counts)), counts, align = "center", color = "tab:blue")
ax.set_yticks(y_tick)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_ax, size = 8)

#annotate bar plot with values
for i, y in enumerate(ax.patches):
    label_per = percents[i]
    ax.text(y.get_width()+.09, y.get_y()+.3, str(round((y.get_width()), 1)), fontsize=10)
    # add the percent label here
    # ax.text(y.get_width()+.09, y.get_y()+.3, str(round((label_per), 2)), ha='right', va='center', fontsize=10)
    ax.text(y.get_width()+.09, y.get_y()+.1, str(f'{round((label_per), 2)}%'), fontsize=10)

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

- You can play with the positioning.
- Other formatting options mentioned by [JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc)
- Print both parts of the text in one string with a `\n` in between to get a "natural" line spacing:
- `str(f'{round((y.get_width()), 1)}\n{round((label_per), 2)}%')`
- `ax.text(..., va='center')` to vertically center and be able to use a slightly larger font.
- `ax.set_xlim(0, max(counts) * 1.18)` to get a bit more space for the text.
- Start each line of text with a space to get a natural "horizontal" padding.
- `str(f' {round((label_per), 2)}%')`, note the space before `{`.
- `y.get_width()+.09` is extremely close to `y.get_width()` when these values are in the tens of thousands.

[image]