# How to annotate a seaborn barplot with the aggregated value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

How can the following code be modified to show the mean as well as the different error bars on each bar of the bar plot?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("white")

a,b,c,d = [],[],[],[]

for i in range(1,5):
   np.random.seed(i)
   a.append(np.random.uniform(35,55))
   b.append(np.random.uniform(40,70))
   c.append(np.random.uniform(63,85))
   d.append(np.random.uniform(59,80))

data_df =pd.DataFrame({'stages':[1,2,3,4],'S1':a,'S2':b,'S3':c,'S4':d})
print("Delay:")

display(data_df)

          S1         S2         S3         S4
0  43.340440  61.609735  63.002516  65.348984
1  43.719898  40.777787  75.092575  68.141770
2  46.015958  61.244435  69.399904  69.727380
3  54.340597  56.416967  84.399056  74.011136

meansd_df=data_df.describe().loc[['mean', 'std'],:].drop('stages', axis = 1)
display(meansd_df)

sns.set()
sns.set_style('darkgrid',{"axes.facecolor": ".92"}) # (1)
sns.set_context('notebook')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))

x = meansd_df.columns
y = meansd_df.loc['mean',:]
yerr = meansd_df.loc['std',:]
plt.xlabel("Time", size=14)
plt.ylim(-0.3, 100)
width = 0.45

for i, j,k in zip(x,y,yerr): # (2)
    ax.bar(i,j, width, yerr = k, edgecolor = "black",
          error_kw=dict(lw=1, capsize=8, capthick=1))  #  (3)
 ax.set(ylabel = 'Delay')
 from matplotlib import ticker
 ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10)) 
 plt.savefig("Over.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Given the example data, for a [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) with capped error bars, `data_df` must be converted from a wide format, to a tidy (long) format, which can be accomplished with [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)

  - *It is also important to keep in mind that a bar plot shows only the mean (or other estimator) value*

### Sample Data and DataFrame

- `.iloc[:, 1:]` is used to skip the `'stages'` column at column index 0.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# given data_df from the OP, select the columns except stage and reshape to long format
df = data_df.iloc[:, 1:].melt(var_name='set', value_name='val')

# display(df.head())
  set        val
0  S1  43.340440
1  S1  43.719898
2  S1  46.015958
3  S1  54.340597
4  S2  61.609735
```

### Updated as of `matplotlib v3.4.2`

- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)
- See [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details and examples with `.bar_label`.
- Some formatting can be done with the `fmt` parameter, but more sophisticated formatting should be done with the `labels` parameter, as show in [How to add multiple annotations to a barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61718127/7758804).
- Tested with `seaborn v0.11.1`, which is using `matplotlib` as the plot engine.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

# add the plot
sns.barplot(x='set', y='val', data=df, capsize=0.2, ax=ax)

# add the annotation
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[-1], fmt='Mean:\n%.2f', label_type='center')

ax.set(ylabel='Mean Time')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### plot with `seaborn.barplot`

- Using `matplotlib` before version 3.4.2
- The default for the `estimator` parameter is `mean`, so the height of the bar is the mean of the group.
- The bar height is extracted from `p` with `.get_height`, which can be used to annotate the bar.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.barplot(x='set', y='val', data=df, capsize=0.2, ax=ax)

# show the mean
for p in ax.patches:
    h, w, x = p.get_height(), p.get_width(), p.get_x()
    xy = (x + w / 2., h / 2)
    text = f'Mean:\n{h:0.2f}'
    ax.annotate(text=text, xy=xy, ha='center', va='center')

ax.set(xlabel='Delay', ylabel='Time')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Seaborn is most powerfull with long form data. So you might want to transform your data, something like this:

```
sns.barplot(data=data_df.melt('stages', value_name='Delay', var_name='Time'), 
            x='Time', y='Delay',
            capsize=0.1, edgecolor='k')
```

Output:

[image]