# Annotating (adding the values) to figure plot on seaborn (line and bar charts combined)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have below code that produces the graph but my question here is how to add the values (numbers) to the bars and the markers on the lineplot?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
year_flights = flights.groupby('year').sum().reset_index()
year_flights['percentages'] = year_flights['passengers'] / year_flights['passengers'].sum()

print(year_flights)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12,6))
sns.lineplot(data=year_flights['percentages'], marker='o', ax=ax1)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.barplot(data=year_flights, x='year', y='passengers', alpha=0.5, 
ax=ax2, color='grey')

plt.show()
```

I have tried using Matplotlib.pyplot.text() but nothing happens and don't know how to apply it properly (if it can be done this way)

Comment: Here are the same questions as you and the [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64780251/how-to-annotate-a-seaborn-barplot-with-the-aggregated-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64780251/how-to-annotate-a-seaborn-barplot-with-the-aggregated-value).

Comment: Can't find anything regarding the line plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this block before `plt.show()`:

```
for pos, row in year_flights.iterrows():
    ax1.annotate(f"{row['percentages']}", (pos, row['percentages']*0.95),
                 color='k', va='top', ha='center')

    ax2.annotate(f"{row['passengers']}", (pos, row['passengers']*1.05),
                 color='k', ha='center')
```

output:

[image: annotated plot]

Comment: the line values should be the % column no?

Comment: @Neek reading your code again, I think the percentage might not have been computed due to a syntax error (misplaced newline), but this doesn't change the logic.